# How to hide the 'azurewebsites' url from search engines when the site is behind Front Door?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-front-door

Trying to stop the 'azurewebsites' url showing on Google search results, normally I would simply add a redirect rule in the web config like the below:

```
<rule name="Disable Azure Domain" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*.azurewebsites.net" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mysitedomain.org{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

However when using this redirect on this particular site which is behind Azure Front Door it is causing the site to return a 404. I'm presuming that front door must use the azurewebsites url and so this is not a viable solution.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you also [add custom domain to your Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain)?

Answer (score 1):

Found a relatively easy solution to this is to simply add an IP restriction on the app service of type 'Service Tag' and then choose AzureFrontDoor.Backend

Answer (score 0):

> I'm presuming that front door must use the azurewebsites url and so this is not a viable solution.

This is not true. When you create backend in your Front Door, you can select 'Custom host' and specify the custom domain you configured for your app service.
[image].

So solution will look like:

1. Use [custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) for your app service. So, your sites will be like siteA.mysitedomain, siteB.mysitedomain etc.
2. Add backend to Front Door as those custom domain.
3. Finally use redirection rule in web.config as below. Redirect to the Front Door URL (you can [use custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain) there also). This will ensure even if someone points to your sites with .azurewebsites.net URL, they will be redirected to the Front Door entry point. Eventually search engines would not index with azurewebsites.net then.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

[Source of the web.config rule](https://www.zainrizvi.io/blog/block-default-azure-websites-domain/)

Comment: thanks for this response but if I understand it correctly it will required dns changes in order to bind a subdomain to the app service